# Unexpected "=" in mutate statement

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to impute outliers in a tibble by replacing them with NAs. Below is my code:

```
for (i in colnames(numTable)){
  m <- mean(pull(numTable[,i]), na.rm=TRUE)
  s<-sd(pull(numTable[,i]),na.rm=TRUE) 
  numTable %>% 
         mutate(numTable[,i] = replace(numTable[,i], abs(numTable[,i]-m)>3*s,na.rm=TRUE), NA)
}
```

NumTable Looks like this: [image]

I keep getting error messages that says

```
Error: unexpected '=' in:
      " numTable %>% 
        mutate(numTable[,i] ="
```

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need a `for` loop.  You can use `mutate_all` or `mutate_at` i.e. `numTable %>% mutate_all(funs(replace(., abs(.-mean(., na.rm = TRUE))> 3 * sd(., na.rm = TRUE)), NA)`

Comment: I changed it to `numTable %>% 
   mutate_at(funs(replace(numTable[,i], abs(numTable[,i]-m)> 3 * s(numTable[,i], na.rm = TRUE)), NA))` but got errors `Error: Can't create call to non-callable object` @akrun

Comment: I said `mutate_all` instead of `mutate_at`  If you are using `mutate_at`, you need to specify the column index or names

Comment: I am sorry but mutate_all gives the same error.

Comment: It is better you show the `dput` of the example data by updating your post

Comment: Your are assigning the ouput of `replace()` to a column by indexing on `numTable`... But `mutate()` expects the name of a single (new) column there, not a column index.

Answer (score 0):

@akrun's suggested version works, but it has a couple of typos.  After correcting those, the following line of code runs without errors:

```
numTable %>% mutate_all(funs(replace(., abs(. - mean(., na.rm = TRUE)) > 3 * sd(., na.rm = TRUE), NA)))
```

I tested this with the first two columns of your data.  Since the inequality condition is not met in those columns, I re-ran it changing the "3 * sd" to "1 * sd" and obtained the following, which I think reflects what you want:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  M     R
  <dbl> <dbl>
1   138    NA
2   240    14
3    NA     6
4    NA    NA
5   239    20
6   253    10
```

If you're unsure of what's going on here, I suggest you start with a simplified version, such as:

```
numTable %>% mutate_all(funs(. * 100))
```

and then gradually convert it over to the code provided by @akrun.